# Not able to log Selenium browser errors in try/except

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a python script to test that I'm able to log into a url and to verify elements are on the page.

I'd like to capture logs from Selenium when there is any kind of error.

My challenge is that whenever I call the `write_logs` function inside the `NoSuchElementException` exception, the logs written are totally blank.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
import os
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


# function that writes logs to file system
def write_logs(driver):
    log = driver.get_log('browser')
    with open('selenium_browser.log', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(log, outfile, indent=4)

baseurl = 'https://example.com'

username = os.environ.get('USER')
password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')

xpaths = {'usernameTxtBox': "//input[@name='Username']",
          'passwordTxtBox': "//input[@name='Password']",
          'submitButton': "//input[@id='loginButton']"
          }
validate_url = 'https://example.com/page_only_accessible_once_logged_in'

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(baseurl)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).send_keys(username)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()

try:
    logged_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idLoggedInTitle"]')
except NoSuchElementException:
    write_logs(driver)
    driver.close()
    exit("can't login")


try:
    driver.get(validate_url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="titleView!1Title"]')
    print(element.text)
except NoSuchElementException:
    write_logs(driver)
    driver.close()
    exit("Not able to reach url")

write_logs(driver)
driver.close()

print("completed sucessfully")
```

Comment: Are you trying to log the python errors stack? Or are you trying to log the browser console errors?

Comment: Looking to log browser errors from Selenium. Updated question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using `log = driver.get_log('browser')` to create the log, which will only capture browser errors, not selenium errors. If you need to log that selenium raised `NoSuchElementException` while searching for `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="titleView!1Title"]')`, than you need to capture the traceback.

```
import traceback

def write_logs(error_message, stack_trace):
    # print the error message and stack and see if that's what you want to log
    print (error_message + '\n' + stack_trace)
    # if it is, add it to your outfile how you want to record it
    with open('selenium_browser.log', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(error_message + '\n' + stack_trace)

try:
    driver.get(validate_url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="titleView!1Title"]')
    print(element.text)
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    error_message = str(e)
    stack_trace = str(traceback.format_exc())
    write_logs(error_message, stack_trace)
    driver.close()
    exit("Not able to reach url")
```

Comment: what is the use of 'driver' parameter in 'write_logs' function?

Comment: There is no function of the `driver` parameter, good catch. Will update answer to remove it.